# How to update the xml element using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have xml file with photo and user tag.
Now I have my website with browse the image from local pc and upload into web application img folder, after successfully uploading image, it should be show in the website by refreshing website. But the issue is that the xml tag for new browse image is not generating so website is not show the uploaded images in the website.

Below is the code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // Before attempting to save the file, verify
      // that the FileUpload control contains a file.
      if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
          // Call a helper method routine to save the file.
          SaveFile(FileUpload1.PostedFile);


          XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
          //string path = @"C:\Users\khant\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\UploadImageRetrieve\UploadImageRetrieve\photos.xml";
          doc.Load("C:\\Users\\khant\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\UploadImageRetrieve\\UploadImageRetrieve\\photos.xml");
          string filenm = FileUpload1.FileName;

          XmlElement user = doc.CreateElement("user");
          XmlElement photo = doc.CreateElement("photo");
          XmlText phototext = doc.CreateTextNode("img/"+filenm);
          //doc.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings/add").Attributes["value"].Value = "hello";
          //doc.SelectNodes("/appSettings/add").Item(2).Attributes["value"].Value = "hello";

          photo.AppendChild(phototext);
          user.AppendChild(photo);
          doc.Save("C:\\Users\\khant\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\UploadImageRetrieve\\UploadImageRetrieve\\photos.xml");
      }
      else
          // Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
          UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";

  }

  void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file)
  {
      // Specify the path to save the uploaded file to.
      string savePath = "C:\\Users\\khant\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\UploadImageRetrieve\\UploadImageRetrieve\\img\\";

      // Get the name of the file to upload.
      string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

      // Create the path and file name to check for duplicates.
      string pathToCheck = savePath + fileName;

      // Create a temporary file name to use for checking duplicates.
      string tempfileName = "";

      // Check to see if a file already exists with the
      // same name as the file to upload.        
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
      {
          int counter = 2;
          while (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheck))
          {
              // if a file with this name already exists,
              // prefix the filename with a number.
              tempfileName = counter.ToString() + fileName;
              pathToCheck = savePath + tempfileName;
              counter++;
          }

          fileName = tempfileName;

          // Notify the user that the file name was changed.
          UploadStatusLabel.Text = "A file with the same name already exists." +
              "<br />Your file was saved as " + fileName;
      }
      else
      {
          // Notify the user that the file was saved successfully.
          UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
      }

      // Append the name of the file to upload to the path.
      savePath += fileName;

      // Call the SaveAs method to save the uploaded
      // file to the specified directory.
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

  }
}
```

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add user element to your xml document before saving it

```
photo.AppendChild(phototext);
user.AppendChild(photo);
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(user); // this line is required 
doc.Save("C:\\Users\\khant\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\UploadImageRetrieve\\UploadImageRetrieve\\photos.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks Damith I have add the line but It show me error that "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node....my xml file code is as below <userPhotos>
  <user>
    <photo>img/test.jpg</photo>
  </user>
  <user>
    <photo>img/diers.jpg</photo>
  </user>
  <user>
    <photo>img/testpng.png</photo>
  </user>

Comment: But the now the problem is the image which is uploading by button click is store in the img folder of web application but it is not showing inside the img folder in visual studio actually it is save in the img folder... i can see in C:\\Users\\khant\\Documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\UploadImageRetrieve\\UploadImageRetrieve\\img\\...i try to refresh the website still the uploaded image is not showing....if again run the website then only the upload image is showing in website...so do i need to add any postback code? Thanks

Comment: k thx...if you know the code for how to re-bind the list item after upload...then please let me know thanks

Comment: call the same method as you load data first time